# How to dynamically create new text boxes with assigned source values?

Tags: excel, vba, textbox, userform

I have a userform that allows users to enter in information to three text boxes for login deletion.  This data feeds into the excel sheet behind it.  I wanted to make it so after the user enters data into the first box it will create another 3 boxes.  This pattern would repeat.

The first box is assigned to 'Delete Logins!A2

Currently, I have been trying to do this, but to no avail.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
Select Case Left(Target.Address, 2)
    Case Is = "$A"
        Dim cCntrl As Control
        Dim i As Integer

        For i = 0 To 2
            Set cCntrl = UserForm1.Frame10.Controls.Add("Forms.TextBox.1", "Login" & i & Target.Row + 1, True)
            With cCntrl
                .Width = UserForm1.TextBox240.Width
                .Height = UserForm1.TextBox240.Height
                .Top = (10 + UserForm1.TextBox240.Height) * (Target.Row - 3)
                .Left = UserForm1.TextBox154.Left + (UserForm1.TextBox154.Width) * i
                .ControlSource = "'Delete Logins'!" & Chr(65 + i) & Target.Row + 1
            End With
         Next
End Select
End Sub
```

The first three boxes are assigned properly, but it not creating the new text boxes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The text boxes were being created, but I wasn't properly placing them.  They were essentially stacking behind one another.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
Select Case Left(Target.Address, 2)
    Case Is = "$A"
    'If Target.Value <> "" Then
        'If UserForm1 <> Nothing Then
        Dim cCntrl As Control
        Dim i As Integer

        For i = 0 To 2
            Set cCntrl = UserForm1.Frame10.Controls.Add("Forms.TextBox.1", "Login" & i & Target.Row + 1, True)
            With cCntrl
                .Width = UserForm1.TextBox240.Width
                .Height = UserForm1.TextBox240.Height
                .Top = (10 + UserForm1.TextBox240.Height) * (Target.Row - 1)
                .Left = UserForm1.TextBox240.Left + (UserForm1.TextBox240.Width) * i
                .ControlSource = "'Delete Logins'!" & Chr(65 + i) & Target.Row + 1
            End With
         Next
   ' End If
End Select
End Sub
```